# How to typesafe reduce a Collection of Either to only Right

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

Maybe a stupid question but I just don't get it.

I have a `Set<Either<Failure, Success>>` and want to output a `Set<Success>` with Arrow-kt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can map the set like this for right:

```
val successes = originalSet.mapNotNull { it.orNull() }.toSet()
```

or if you want the lefts:

```
val failures = originalSet.mapNotNull { it.swap().orNull() }.toSet()
```

The final `toSet()` is optional if you want to keep it as a `Set` as `mapNotNull` is an extension function on `Iterable` and always returns a `List`

PS: No stupid questions :)

**Update:**
It can be done avoiding `nullables`:

```
val successes = originalSet
  .map { it.toOption() }
  .filter { it is Some }
  .toSet()
```

We could potentially add `Iterable<Option<A>>.filterSome` and `Iterable<Either<A, B>.mapAsOptions` functions.

**Update 2:**

That last example returns a `Set<Option<Success>>`. If you want to unwrap the results without using `null` then one thing you can try is to fold the `Set`:

```
val successes = originalSet
  .fold(emptySet<Success>()) { acc, item -> 
    item.fold({ acc }, { acc + it })
  }
```

This last option (unintended pun) doesn't require the use of `Option`.

Comment: is it just me or is calling a filter function mapNotNull not deeply confusing?

Comment: @jk It's not a `filter` function, it's short for `map().filterNotNull()`. Similar to having `flatMap()` being short for `map().flatten()` (I guess that one is strange since the order of names changes)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am not quite happy with this, but it does the trick.

Comment: I mean I have Option or Either to not introduce `null` but this forces me to do so, at least in a narrow scope.

Comment: @sschrass I've added an example without `null`

Comment: Cool, because it looks more idiomatic, This is what I tried with .filter { it is Either.Right}.